# How to export nested JSON file items to HTML table using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to export JSON file data to a table but I'm not sure how to access nested elements of the JSON file.

This is my JSON:

```
{
"fruits color": "red",
"farmers market": "2019",
"sellers": [{
    "day": "1",
    "seller": [{
            "name": "John",
            "sales": "50",
            "types": "3",
            "type": [
                "apples",
                "strawberries",
                "rapsberries"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Adam",
            "sales": "45",
            "types": "2",
            "type": [
                "cranberries",
                "redcurrants"
            ]
        }
    ]
}   
]}
```

I have a simple HTML  form where I can select the file from a drop-down menu.

When my file is selected my JavaScript function pulls the information from it and sends it to a table:

```
function fruitSelection() {
var items = document.getElementById("fruit-colors");
var value = items.options[items.selectedIndex].value;
    if (value == "red") {
        JSON = "redfruits.json"
        processFruitsFile()}}

function processFruitsFile() {
  $.getJSON(JSON, function(JSONdata) {
    var JSONItems= [];

$.each(JSONdata, function(key, value) {
        JSONItems.push( "<tr" + key + "'>" + value + "</tr>");
});
    $( "<tr/>", {
        "class": "result-items",
        html: JSONItems.join("")
}).appendTo(result);});}
```

Now the problem I'm having is that my function works only with the first key and value pair like this:
 `red2019[object Object]`

What I'm trying to achieve is a table where I can display something like this:

```
Day Seller Type 1   Type 2        Type 3
1   John   apples   strawberries  raspberries
```

How can I access those values that are nested inside 'seller' and 'type of fruits' and format them nicely?

Thanks for help!

Comment: You want `Type 1, Type 2....` in main header of table?

Comment: You need to flatten the json first, and then convert to table. There are couple of questions already on flatten'ing the object, check them out

Comment: @MaheerAli Yes, I've updated the JSON file as well to make it more clear. I would like to display the types of fruits for each vendor. The maximum is 3 types. If a vendor sells 2 types then that row would have only 2 types but 3 headers, third type under the header would be empty in that case.

Comment: I have given the answer. You said _third type under the header would be empty_. By this you mean that you don't want the cell be there like in answer or just want empty cell?

Comment: @Maheer Thank you! An empty cell would be great, it looks more tidy that way.

Comment: @rootpl  Ok i have updated the code. Accept the answer if it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is way to do that using Javascript

```js
let obj = {
"fruits color": "red",
"farmers market": "2019",
"sellers": [{
    "day": "1",
    "seller": [{
            "name": "John",
            "sales": "50",
            "types": "3",
            "types of fruits": [
                "apples",
                "strawberries",
                "rapsberries"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Adam",
            "sales": "45",
            "types": "2",
            "types of fruits": [
                "cranberries",
                "redcurrants"
            ]
        }
    ]
}   
]}
function createTable(obj){
  let table = document.createElement('table'); 
  table.className = 'table';
  let thead = document.createElement('thead');
  let tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
  let noOfFriuts = 0;
  let {sellers}  = obj 
  for(let day of sellers){ 
    for(let seller of day.seller){
      let tr = document.createElement('tr');
      tr.innerHTML += `<td>${day.day}</td>`
      tr.innerHTML += `<td>${seller.name}</td>`
      for(let fruit of seller['types of fruits']){ 
        
        tr.innerHTML += `<td>${fruit}</td>`
      }
      noOfFriuts  = Math.max(noOfFriuts ,seller['types of fruits'].length);
      tbody.appendChild(tr)
    }
    
  }
  let tr = document.createElement('tr');
  tr.innerHTML = `<th>Day</th>
    <th>Name</th>`  
  for(let i = 1;i<=noOfFriuts;i++){
    let th = document.createElement('th');
    th.innerHTML = `Type ${i}`
    tr.appendChild(th)
  }
  
  thead.appendChild(tr);
  table.appendChild(thead);
  table.appendChild(tbody);
  document.body.appendChild(table);
  document.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(tr => {
    let dif = -(tr.cells.length - noOfFriuts - 2);
    for(let i = 0;i<dif;i++) tr.innerHTML += "<td></td>"
  })
  
}
console.log('x')
createTable(obj);
```

```css
table{
  padding:2px;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border:2px solid;
}
td,th{
border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to implement your solution but I want to read the JSON data from a file instead from the JS file. I'm trying to use variable instead like so: let obj = "fruits.json" but I'm getting an error saying "sellers" is undefined.